# How to update multiple graphs from one plot in one statement in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, cell-array

I have something like this:

```
p = plot([0 1], [0 1], [1 2], [1 2]);
```

I want to take each pair and append another number.

```
x = get(p, 'XData');
y = get(p, 'YData');

x1 = mat2cell([x{1} double(2)]);
y1 = mat2cell([y{1} double(2)]);

x2 = mat2cell([x{2} double(3)]);
y2 = mat2cell([y{2} double(3)]);

set(p, 'XData', [x1; x2], 'YData', [y1; y2]); % this does not work

drawnow;
```

'get' is giving me some data in a format and I am 'set'-ing back in the same format the data with one more value for each pair.

The error I get is: Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do to the plot? What error do you get?

Comment: Add more values to the graphs and refresh the plot.

Comment: Could you give a (working) example of how the result would be produced if you wanted to plot the data including additions manually?

Comment: Sure, initially I have 2 graphs:
G1: x: 0, 1 | y: 0, 1
G2: x: 1, 2 | y: 1, 2

After addition:
G1: x: 0, 1, 2 | y: 0, 1, 2
G2: x: 1, 2, 3 | y: 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to fetch the current plot points and add to them. The first two lines of [Eitan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447866/52738) (using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)) are one way. Here's one using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
newX = [2 3];  % New x values to add
newY = [2 3];  % New y values to add
X = num2cell([cell2mat(get(p,'XData')) newX(:)], 2);
Y = num2cell([cell2mat(get(p,'YData')) newY(:)], 2);
```

The key issue to note when using the [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) function on multiple handles is stated in this excerpt from the documentation:

> set(H,pn,MxN_pv) sets n property values on each of m graphics objects, where m = length(H) and n is equal to the number of property names contained in the cell array pn. This allows you to set a given group of properties to different values on each object.

As a result, your single call to `set` has to look like this:

```
set(p, {'XData'}, X, {'YData'}, Y);
```

Note that `length(p)` is equal to 2, the property strings are placed in cell arrays, and `X` and `Y` are each 2-by-1 cell arrays.

Comment: So that's how you call `set` with cell array inputs... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand and I don't want to bash the language because I'm not very experienced but I feel the documentation is not that great and most of the times I feel that I'm scratching my right ear with my left hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try redrawing the plot:

```
xcoor = cellfun(@horzcat, get(p, 'XData'), {2; 3}, 'UniformOutput', false);
ycoor = cellfun(@horzcat, get(p, 'YData'), {2; 3}, 'UniformOutput', false);
c = [xcoor; ycoor];
plot(c{:})
```

Comment: "Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y"
Also I want to add values to the graphs I don't want to flatten them into a single one.

Comment: "Vectors must be the same lengths."

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove the handle `p` from the plot command. Please try again.

Comment: It seems it works on the example above what you wrote but for "p = plot([0 1 1], [0 1 0], [5 6 6], [5 6 5]);" not that great.

Comment: Why not? It adds a value to each cell array as desired, no?

Comment: Yes the values are added but the plot is not what is expected, I appreciate your answer though.

Comment: @usre2704 No problem. Perhaps it'll be more helpful to visualize the expected result next time :)